# Python Bisection for list of list

Tags: python, python-3.8

If I have the following code...

```
from bisect import bisect_right
a = [[0, 0], [3, 5], [3,9]]
print(bisect_right(a, [3]))

b = [0, 3, 3]
print(bisect_right(b, 3))
```

I get the following output

```
1
3
```

which is contrary to what I would expect.
As far as I understand, Python should use the first element of each list in `a` to determine the ordering. Then it follows, according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) the first output should be `3` instead of `1` since

> The returned insertion point i partitions the array a into two halves so that all(val <= x for val in a[lo:i]) for the left side and all(val > x for val in a[i:hi]) for the right side.

It seems to be correct in the second case. Why is it printing `1` in the first case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because the insertion point for `[3]` into `[[0, 0], [3, 5], [3,9]]` is `1`, to maintain sort order. Using that index, the result would be `[[0, 0], [3], [3, 5], [3,9]]`, which is correct. A result of `3` would not be correct, inserting at `3` would result in `[[0, 0], [3, 5], [3,9], [3]]`, which is not correctly sorted.

Comment: Python uses all elements of a `list`/`tuple`: Just test it for yourself `[3, 5] < [3, 9]`

Comment: I see that makes sense. If I wanted 3 I should do bisect_right(a, [3, 1<< 30 ]) or some other large number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first element in a list isn't the only factor in ordering. When the first elements are equal, the next element is also compared. Since `[3]` doesn't have a second element, it is deemed lesser.

```
[3] < [3, 5]
# True

[3, 5] < [3, 9]
# True

[3, 9] < [3, 5]
# False
```

Answer (score 2):

Python uses lexicographical ordering for sequences. You can imagine the list elements as the characters in a string. If I asked you for the result of

```
bisect_right(['a', 'ba', 'bb'], 'b')
```

you would immediately tell me 1, not 3. Obviously 'b' < 'ba'. The same thing applies to lists, whether `['b'] < ['b', 'a']` or `[3] < [3, 5]`.